# How to change 'pixel' media queries to 'em' based media queries in twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I want to change the 'pixel' based media in twitter bootstrap 3 to 'em' based media queries.

so for example:

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px){} would equal to @media only screen and (max-width: 20){}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){} would equal to @media only screen and (max-width: 30){} etc.

Is there a easier way to do this in the bootstrap.css file rather than changing all the media queries manually which would take a lot of time to do.

Thanks in advance

Raj

Answer (score 1):

You can update the media queries manually in `bootstrap.css` file and it will only take you a moment.

Follow this pattern `target/context = result` to convert `px` values to `em`. IMPORTANT: Media queries defined with em are always based off 16px no matter what the base font size is set to (in Bootstrap 3 it's 14px).

```
h2{
  font-size: 2em /* 32px / 16px = 2em */
}
```

to

```
@media (min-width: 48em) {} /* 768px / 16px = 48em */
```

Do it for all media queries in `bootstrap.css` and you will be done.

Comment: And if you're using the sass version of the BT, you can simply do it by overwriting the variables in one place, and voila.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the boostrap customizer to change your media queries to ems, but I haven't yet confirmed this. http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score -2):

you just add 'em' at the end of the value, as I edit now

@media only screen and (max-width: 320em)
{ max-width:320em; width:100%;}

Comment: Hi, wouldn't 320px be 20em (320/16) 16 being the base font size. Also, there is hundreds of media queries to change there must be a quicker way to change this via LESS or SASS.

Comment: Hi does anyone know how do this?